# Sloppy elements design doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari

I'm working with sloppy elements design. Everything is going well and my website is nearly done, but I find out that I have problems with Safari, my elements aren't slopped, it look like transform doesn't work. :(

I'm developing in Chrome, and all other browsers everything works fine, but Safari don't.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Please show us what code you have and what you see in Safari that you call "it doesn't work"

Comment: See this website in Chrome and in Safari http://motiongiraffx.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-webkit-transform` for Safari browser

Note: you can use both in the same rule.

```
element {
    transform: skewY(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-10deg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!!! You save my day! :)